# how to show/hide a div if a variable isset?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some variables in PHP that I pull out from a database. I want that a certain div in the page shows only when that variable pulls out a specific result.

I came across something like that but it doesn't work. Anybody can help me?

```html
<?php  if ($piano == '7'){?>
  <script>
    $("#wellness").show();
  </script>
<?php } else { ?>
  <script>
    $("#wellness").hide();
  </script>
<?php } ?>


<div id="wellness">wellness</div>
```

Comment: It's because you are not loading the scripts after the HTML is loaded. Also, this is not the way you do it using PHP. You directly act on the place where the wellness `div` is.

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumarPurushothaman how can i do it properly?

Comment: <?php 
if ($piano == '7') {
echo '<div id="wellness">wellness</div>';
} ?>

Comment: @StefanoZanetti Yea, something like the above and the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  if ($piano == '7'){?>
  <div id="wellness">wellness</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Instead of using javascript you can use php IF condition to show it or not. Now the `div` will only show if `$piano` is 7